# How to not allow useState to automatically add undefined type to state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

in my memory.

```
const [total, setTotal] = useState<Total>()
```

This will report an error that: "Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Total'"

Now I find that no error will be reported. And my state will have two types, the type I defined and undefined

```
total: Total | undefined
```

Comment: give it an init value

Comment: So you want to know how `const [total, setTotal] = useState<Total>()` has to be changed in order to allow `undefined` values as well?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an initial value passed to `useState`, so initialize your state with a value.